# AngularJS orderyby on two digits

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

JS:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('orderByExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.friends =
        [{name:'John', phone:'2-3-7', age:10},
         {name:'Mary', phone:'2-3-9', age:19},
         {name:'Mike', phone:'10-21-30', age:21},
         {name:'Adam', phone:'1-5-9', age:35},
         {name:'Julie', phone:'9-15-20', age:29}];
    $scope.predicate = 'phone';
    $scope.reverse = true;
    $scope.order = function(predicate) {
      $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
      $scope.predicate = predicate;
    };
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

HTML:

```
<table class="friend">
    <tr>        
     <th>
         <button ng-click="order('phone')">Phone Number</button>
         <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'phone'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
     </th>         
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:predicate">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Result:

**Number**

- 2-3-7
- 2-3-9
- 10-21-30
- 9-15-20
- 1-5-9

But i want this result:

**Number**

- 1-5-9
- 2-3-7
- 2-3-9
- 9-15-20
- 10-21-30

I want to sort based on **Number** only

Here is the plunker link:
http://plnkr.co/edit/QPNVtKQCqk2nYYkFx4aX?p=preview

Comment: Do you want to sort on the basis of 'age' and 'phone'?

Comment: i want sort only on the base of phone

Comment: those aren't numbers....they are strings. If you want to sort by number you need to generate a number to sort by

Comment: Your plunker (which doesn't match either the actual or expected result in your question) is working exactly as I would expect it to, given that phone is a string.

Comment: If i changed them into number then negative result of expression would come which i don't want.Any other work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort by numeric representation of the phone. For example like this:

```
$scope.friends = [...].map(function(friend) {
    friend.phoneNumber = Number(friend.phone.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));
    return friend;
});
```

And then in template use `phoneNumber` for ordering:

```
<th>
     <button ng-click="order('phoneNumber')">Phone Number</button>
     <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'phoneNumber'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
</th>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/CgYc5wRBmJLMWDfG74gI?p=info